# Xcode 11.1 crashes when tried to record in login screen in safari browser for writing UI Tests

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, crash, xcuitest

I am trying to write the XCUITest test case for Microsoft SSO login but my Xcode getting crashed every time if navigating on the SSO webpage or any other safari page from the application.

Some developers already reported this bug on the Apple forum for Xcode 9.3.
As per the Apple Xcode 10 release note, they have resolved this bug in Xcode 10.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes

I have tried with both Xcode 10.3 and Xcode 11.1 and getting the same issue every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to record the SSO login automation element somehow using below trick-

I have recorded the element using the iPad instead of the iPhone and it's working fine for me. I know this is a weird solution but working for me.